# Adding Route on EC2 Instances across Subnets

Tags: amazon-ec2, routing

I am setting up "keepalived" on EC2 instances. I have three EC2 instances. One virtual IP is configured in a `vrrp_instance`

Internal addresses:

```
EC1 10.0.1.149 
EC2 10.0.0.74
EC3 10.0.1.216
```

All are in same VPC.

For keepalived the unicast address and virtual address is as follows:

```
unicast_src_ip 10.0.1.149 #EC1
 unicast_peer {
10.0.0.74 #EC2  
#addresses swap in case of EC2
}

virtual_ipaddress {
   10.0.55.1
 }
```

The master and slave ownership of the virtual address - 10.0.55.1 works fine.

Now, if virtual IP is with EC1, in order to allow a TCP client from EC3 with address 10.0.1.216, I add the route as follows in EC3

```
route add 10.0.55.1 gw 10.0.1.149
```

With this client in EC3 can connect to server in EC1 on the virtual IP.

Now when I try doing the same `route add` in EC2, error is seen.

```
 `route add 10.0.55.1 gw 10.0.0.74`
`SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`
```

Though EC3 can reach 10.0.0.74.

`ifconfig` output from EC3:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:02:55:4F:0A:47  
          inet addr:10.0.0.74  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Any suggestions in having the right routing in AWS EC2 instances is appreciated.

Comment: You need to verify the `gw ip_addr` part of the route command contains a valid IP address within the same subnet of one of your machine interfaces. Otherwise, you will get this error when adding the static route. Show the IP/mask of machine your are executing this command on.

Comment: @Khaled, I have updated the question with IP details of EC3.